# How do I check for covariates and how do I adjust for them?

Tags: regression, spss

My data:

1. My outcome variable (Outvar) is binary (yes/no)
2. My explanatory variable (exvar) is also binary (yes/no)
3. I have 3 extra variables:

   - Variable A is binary
   - Variable B is continuous but not normally distributed
   - Variable C is also continuous and has normal distribution

I know from background that VarA, VarB and VarC will probably affect my outcome and *maybe* my explanatory variable.

For the varA, varB and varC, I want to check if they impact the relationship between outvar and exvar. If they do I want to “remove” their impact because I want to know the independent impact of my exvar on outvar. What steps should I take?

And, do I need to check the impact of varA, varB, var C on my exvar too?

I am thinking multiple linear regression but I am not sure at all. Can someone describe the steps please?

PS. I am using the SPSS but you don't have to tell me the steps based on that. I am not sure about which test to use and what steps I should follow if I had pen and paper only. I am using the SPSS secondarily.

Comment: I would start by looking at logistic regression, (a generalized linear model). It doesn't matter that much how your continuous variables are distributed. If anything, it's more a question of whether they predict the outcome in a linear way (vs whether a transformation (like log(varB) has a more linear relationship). It would help to know the no. observations involved. I would also start by examining crosstabulations of the outcome vs the non-continuous predictors.

Answer (score 2):

If your outcome variable is dichotomous, then logistic regression is the place to start; linear regression cannot be correct here.

In statistics, we call "removing their effect" *controlling*. To control for variables we simply enter them into the right side of the regression equation. Then the result for exvar will account for those. Whether to include them is a question of model development or variable selection, which is a big topic that has been discussed a lot here. My view is that if you have theoretical reasons to include them, you should include them.

However, if the exvar is strongly related to varA, varB or varC you may have problems with collinearity.